# How to validate before request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to check data before sending it to the server side, 
On my code I want to run the js validation and cancel the request if fromid >= toid

My code

```js
jQuery('#btndeletereg').click(function () {
    if (jQuery('#txtuserrangefrom').val() >= jQuery('#txtuserrangeto').val()) {
        alert("Range is not possible");
    }
});
```

```html
<label for="txtuserrangefrom">From User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangefrom" name="txtuserrangefrom" type="number" />
<span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<label for="txtuserrangeto">To User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangeto" name="txtuserrangeto" type="number" />
<input id="btndeletereg" class="btn" type="button" value="Delete all users in range" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteRangeUsers", "ControlPanel")?fromid=' + $('#txtuserrangefrom').val() + '&toid=' + $('#txtuserrangeto').val()" />
<br />
```

Thanks in advance

P.S
I debugged my code and it seems that Get request trigged before JS function

EDIT:
problem solved,
deleted the "onclick" event from my html input tag and put it in my jquery code as you all recommended.
Thank you all

Comment: Maybe [asp.net mvc client side validation not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21985782/205233) has some hints for you.

Comment: Since you are binding the click event and you are writing validation logic in it. Then, you can place your `location.href...` code inside that  function and make sure it will execute only after the data is validated

Answer (score 1):

Don't use onclick attribute, redirect your application in the same function.

More clear and maintanable.

```js
jQuery('#btndeletereg').click(function (e) {
    if (jQuery('#txtuserrangefrom').val() >= jQuery('#txtuserrangeto').val()) {
      alert("Range is not possible");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      alert("ok");
      window.location.href="yoururl";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="txtuserrangefrom">From User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangefrom" name="txtuserrangefrom" type="number" />
<span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<label for="txtuserrangeto">To User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangeto" name="txtuserrangeto" type="number" />
<input id="btndeletereg" class="btn" type="button" value="Delete all users in range" />
<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="btndeletereg" class="btn" type="button" value="Delete all users in range" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteRangeUsers", "ControlPanel")?fromid=' + $('#txtuserrangefrom').val() + '&toid=' + $('#txtuserrangeto').val()" />
```

> This one is not working because on your button click you are
>   redirecting on **DeleteRangeUsers** action of your **ControlPanel**
>   controller this is the main issue

**Remove your button onclick event and redirect using jquery code as follow.**

```
jQuery('#btndeletereg').click(function (e) {
    if (jQuery('#txtuserrangefrom').val() >= jQuery('#txtuserrangeto').val()) {
      alert("Range is not possible");
      return false;
    }            
    window.location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteRangeUsers", "ControlPanel")?fromid=' + $('#txtuserrangefrom').val() + '&toid=' + $('#txtuserrangeto').val();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code, you need to remember this,

First thing, you have `click` event in the html element tag, and another `click` event is you are binding through `JQuery`. The fact is, `JQuery` appended your `click` event to the one which is already there, so it will be **after** the click event which is there in `html`. Because of this, your `JQuery` `click` event is triggered later.
My suggestion is to place the logic which you have written in the `html` `onclick` into the jq `click` event which you are binding.
So your code will be,

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery('#btndeletereg').click(function () {
    if (jQuery('#txtuserrangefrom').val() >= jQuery('#txtuserrangeto').val()) {
        alert("Range is not possible");
    }else{
        //Your logic which you prefer after validation is success
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="txtuserrangefrom">From User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangefrom" name="txtuserrangefrom" type="number" />
<span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<label for="txtuserrangeto">To User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangeto" name="txtuserrangeto" type="number" />
<input id="btndeletereg" class="btn" type="button" value="Delete all users in range"/>
<br />
```

**OR**

There is another way, don't bind the event in the `JQuery`. Instead create a validation function which will return `boolean`, and call it before your login in `onclick`.

**JavaScript**

```
function validate() {
    if (jQuery('#txtuserrangefrom').val() >= jQuery('#txtuserrangeto').val()) {
        alert("Range is not possible");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**html**

```
<label for="txtuserrangefrom">From User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangefrom" name="txtuserrangefrom" type="number" />
<span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<label for="txtuserrangeto">To User ID</label>
<input id="txtuserrangeto" name="txtuserrangeto" type="number" />
<input id="btndeletereg" class="btn" type="button" value="Delete all users in range" onclick="return validate();location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteRangeUsers", "ControlPanel")?fromid=' + $('#txtuserrangefrom').val() + '&toid=' + $('#txtuserrangeto').val()" />
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#btndeletereg').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#txtuserrangefrom').val() >= $('#txtuserrangeto').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Range is not possible");
        return false;
    }
});
```