# Data Annotations / Validation not working for partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have some partial views loaded at runtime, based on user input.

```
$("#Categories").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Product/Create" + $("#Categories option:selected").text().replace(/\s+/, ""),
            type: "Get"
        }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#partialDiv").html(partialViewResult);
        });
    });
```

The POCO's that are used in the view model are decorated with data annotations, but they are not triggered.

The partial views each contain a form (Html.BeginForm()).

I guess I'm doing something wrong, but not sure what.  Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that the 'data annotations are not triggered'? Do you mean form validation does not work? That's a different problem.

Comment: The problem is that your dynamically adding the form to the DOM. You need to re parse the validator. [This article](http://memoriesdotnet.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/unobtrusive-validation-in-jquery-has.html) should help.

Comment: @CornéM Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke.  Will take a look at that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Include JS files i.e `Jquery Unobtrusive js` file in your Partial View also then it work fine ,some times this problem comes in partial view in asp.net mvc.

Just include this js file in your Partial View also :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

------------------OR try this in Partial View--------------------------

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));
```

Comment: I think this is because you are adding a new form from script without the page reloading - the new forms' events then aren't hooked up to the validation scripts?

Comment: That was a ridiculous nasty bug

Comment: @BrianOgden..just read comments on  this page carefully its not a bug actually...

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working for me ! Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

try this if you are appending form in html

```
var formid = $("#frmAddProduct");
formid.unbind();
formid.data("validator", null);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#frmAddProduct"));
```

OR use in partial view on document ready

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));
```