# Data Annotations not working jquery unobtrusive validation in Partial ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

So I am trying to use the following DataAnnotations:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Description Is Required.")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "The Description must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string description { get; set; }
```

The DataAnnotations populate data attributes in my `<input />` element response to client for my description property:

```
<input maxlength="500" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Description must be at least 2 characters long." data-val-length-max="500" data-val-length-min="2" data-val-required="A Description Is Required." id="Add_description" name="Add.description" required="required" type="text" value="">
```

I am referencing script/js libraries:

```
jQuery Validation Plugin 1.13.1
Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation 3.2.2
Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax 3.2.2
```

I am not sure if I need the Microsoft jQuery Unobstrusive Ajax library but I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370768/mvc-data-annotations-range-validation-not-working-properly) as I am also attempting a Range validation which is not working but I am focusing on the Required message for my description property for this question, to keep it simple.

Here is my View code (please understand my Bootstrap modal is HTML syntactically correct I have just excluded some of my HTML elements for the Bootstrap modal to make the code easier to read for my question):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CustomFieldAddNew", "CustomField", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form", id = "CustomFieldAddForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(mi => mi.Add.custom_field_context_id)

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">General Information </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="">Description<i class="icon-asterisk"></i></label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 padding-0">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(mi => mi.Add.description, new { @class = "form-control", @MaxLength = "500", required = "required" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(mi => mi.Add.description)
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btnCloseSaveModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="btnCustomFieldSave" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        }

<script>
        $('#btnCustomFieldSave').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).parents('form');

        var postData = {
            description: $('#@Html.IdFor(mi => mi.Add.description)').val()
        }

        if ($form.validate().form()) {//fire jQuery validation
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                contentType:"application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    toastr.error("Error saving, please try again.");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#customField').modal('toggle');
                    $form.trigger("reset");
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

My client side validation message should say:

```
"A Description Is Required."
```

But instead, when I click `btnCustomFieldSave`, and my jQuery `CLICK` listener function fires and calls $form.validate() the validation error message reads "This field is required." This is the default message in the jQuery Validation Plugin 1.13.1 library.

**My question is, why is my DataAnnotation message "A Description Is Required" not displaying in place of the canned jQuery Validation Plugin message "This field is required"**

Note, whether I include the line `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(mi => mi.Add.description)` or not. I am still seeing "This field is required" instead of my custom message defined in the DataAnnotation attribute `Required` which is "A Description is Required"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation has already fired its parse and binded to data attrs before my Partial form content was loaded.

I needed to have Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation parse fire again, so at the bottom of my Partial I added:

```
$(function () {
        //Microsoft Unobtrusive jQuery validation has already binded so must kick off parse to bind partial loaded dynamic form
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#CustomFieldAddForm'));
});
```

I found the answer here: [Data Annotations / Validation not working for partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258719/data-annotations-validation-not-working-for-partial-views)