# Client-Side Validation MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I am newer to using MVC.  I am trying to set up client-side validation using the build in data annotations.  I have read a few tutorials but can't seem to get it to work.  When I click my form submit button, it still POSTS instead of displaying the error message to inform me no description was provided.  Below is my class code and my view code:

Class Code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace TicketSystem.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class TICKET
{
    public decimal id { get; set; }
    public string empId { get; set; }
    public short severityId { get; set; }
    public short statusId { get; set; }
    public short categoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required!!")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string logOfActions { get; set; }
    public string deviceType { get; set; }
    public string deviceSerNum { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
 }
}
```

View Code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.description, "Description:")
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.description, new { rows = 5, @class = "txtBoxDescr" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.description)
```

Comment: Can you show more of the view code? How are you constructing the form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 4 client side validation not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520336/mvc-4-client-side-validation-not-working)

Comment: Two most frequent issue to check: 1.Make sure you enabled unobstrusive validation in web.config 2.Make sure your page have the following javascript referenced and in right order: jquery, jquery.validate, jquery.validate.unobstrusive

Comment: I have the values enabled in web.config and the scrips are rendered in that order in my _Layout.cshtml but still doesn't work

Comment: Any JS errors on page? An errant piece of JS code can break all further JS on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, be sure to use the following code:

```
if ModelState.IsValid()
{
  //Do Something here
   return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

`return View(myModel);`

You can check a better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881281/what-is-modelstate-isvalid-valid-for-in-asp-net-mvc-in-nerddinner).