# validating date in the datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers:

```
$(".From").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
numberOfMonths: 1,
autoclose: true,
onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $(".To").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
}});


$(".To").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
numberOfMonths: 1,
autoclose: true,
onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $(".From").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
}});
```

View:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From, new { @class = "form-control From" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.To, new { @class = "form-control To" })
```

Model:

```
    [Display(Name = "From")]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To")]
    public string To { get; set};
```

When the user manually enters the date, it fails.

Is there a way to allow users to enter the date and validate it?

option 1: Should I use regex?

Comment: Model, View, Con.. wait, which framework are you using..?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say "it fails"? What exactly happens and what do you expect to happen? Also, you don't appear to have any validation rules to validate against.

Comment: @Jasen It is not validating the date entered by the user. For ex: 11/13/2014 as 13th month does not exist. Expected output : "Please enter a valid date" - as a error message  which must be added to validation rules. Should I use data annotation?

Comment: Well, you would need to use _something_ and Data Annotations with ValidationMessageFor helper is a good built-in tool to validate input. You may possibly need to use the `DateTime` data type for this to work. What you have now will programmatically restrict options but does not explicitly validate input. Another option is to prevent direct keyboard entry so the only values available are via the datepicker widget -- which should be _valid_ dates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example

**Model**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
[DisplayName(Name = "From")]
public DateTime? From { get; set; }  // note the data type
```

**View**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From, new { @class = "form-control From" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.From)
```

Don't forget to [load the validation scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520336/mvc-4-client-side-validation-not-working).

```
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

This will give you a validation error message when you attempt to type a bad date.

Comment: It didn't work for me- that throws an error : The field must be a date. so I have used the datatype string. and when the user enters  11/13/2014  "To" field is set to 24/06/2020

Comment: It didn't work for me. Throws an error for valid dates as:  Field must be a date- which is not right. I tried this before and changed to datatype string

Comment: I guess we need to use something like this.. var validator = $( "#From" ).validate();
validator.showErrors({
  "From": "Please enter a valid date "
});

Comment: It looks like you're having [date culture format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548816/mvc-4-date-culture-issue) issues. If you use instead `dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'` this may work. However, it would be nice to specify a different format -- which the linked post explains in detail.

Comment: Yes, It accepts the format mm/dd/yy. But we need the format dd/mm/yy. In order to overcome that error, it is changed to string.

Comment: can you send me the link of that post again please

Comment: It is a link in the comment. But here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548816/mvc-4-date-culture-issue

Comment: I have already included the <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" /> in web.config