# MVC Validation attributes are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

MVC Validation attributes are not working. When i hit the Submit button without entering any data in add view,it supposed to throw an Validation error but it's not throwing validation error. 
I have added validation attributes to the model and also check ModelState property, but still it's not working

In my config file,have the below settings

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Below is the model I'm refering to the view.

```
public class Student
{
    public int StuID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Student Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required!")]
    public string StuName  { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Mention Education!")]
    public string Education { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Birth Date")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gender")]
    public string Sex { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Course Name!")]
    public string Course { get; set; }
    //public string Location { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Location")]
    public int LocID { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number Required!")]
    public String Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Add(Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student(StuName,Education,Sex,Course,BirthDate,LocID,Contact) Values(@StuName,@Education,@Sex,@Course,@BirthDate,@LocID,@Contact) ", SqlCon);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StuName", student.StuName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Education", student.Education);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", student.Sex);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", student.Course);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", student.BirthDate.HasValue ? (object)student.BirthDate : DBNull.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocID", student.LocID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", string.IsNullOrEmpty(student.Contact) ? DBNull.Value : (object)student.Contact);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I have checked the **ModelState** property also in controller but still it is not working. Am i missing something here?

Comment: What is not working? What object do you pass into the method?

Comment: Ensure you have loaded required jquery library as suggested in these posts - 

https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520336/mvc-4-client-side-validation-not-working

Comment: Could you confirm that you have added [HttpPost] attribute? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model#how-validation-occurs-in-the-create-view-and-create-action-method

Comment: Please add the html code of the view here.